# Two tableviews error while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am using two tableviews adjacently on a scrollview..

scrollview - screen Width * 2   which can be scrollable horizontal only.
two tableviews on it, only any one tableview appears in the screen for scrolls.

for each tableview i am getting the data from server and i am saving it locally.

the problem here is if the row count of tableview to which i want to show after scrolling, the program is crashing as it is taking the index value of previous one.

suppose iam having 10 items in first tableview array and 20 in second tableview array.
if i moved to second tableview and scrolls up to 20 index and if i scroll back to first table view while tableview is scrolling, it is searching for the index path 20. So i am getting the error.

if i scroll back to first tableview when tableview is not scrolling i am not getting any error even if the current index path of second tableview is 20.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (selecetedSearchIndex == 0){
        UITableViewCell *cell ;
       // code for cell

        return cell;
    }
    else{
        UITableViewCell *cell ;
       // code for cell

        return cell;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    if (selecetedSearchIndex == 0)
    {
       return firstArr.count;
    }
    else{
        return secondArr.count;
    }
}
```

// selecetedSearchIndex is the index value to identify the tableview showing on the screen

Can anyone help me on this....

Comment: Add more code please. We need to know how did you add these tableViews to your scrollView.

Comment: I am sorry, but why you need to use 2 table views inside a scroll view?? Why not just one table view with 2 sections - you can customise cells after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incomplete But most common solution for this type of problem is to first stop the scrolling of one tableview before scrolling the other tableview

```
[tableView setContentOffset:tableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

if this doesn't work please share your crash logs

Answer (score -1):

it can't calculate the height to be provided simultaneously. the simple solution would be to make constraint outlet of its height and setting its constant programmatically.

////////////
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

///////////
heightConstraint.constant = 100;